# BUSQUEDA EN COLUMNAS INDIVIDUALES - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, mvc, datatables

Quiero hacer una búsqueda en varias columnas. Algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé como hacerlo en Laravel ya que se maneja por medio de MVC.

La pagina de DATATABLES sugiere que ingrese este codigo.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

} );

La tabla la tengo actualmente luce así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo del controlador.**

```js
<?php
/**
 * Controller genrated using LaraAdmin
 * Help: http://laraadmin.com
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers\LA;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Validator;
use Datatables;
use Collective\Html\FormFacade as Form;
use Dwij\Laraadmin\Models\Module;
use Dwij\Laraadmin\Models\ModuleFields;

use App\Models\Computer;

class ComputersController extends Controller
{
 public $show_action = true;
 public $view_col = 'n_serie';
 public $listing_cols = ['id', 'empresa', 'departamento', 'codigo', 'marca', 'modelo', 'n_serie', 'tipo', 'procesador', 'vel_procesador'];
 
 public function __construct() {
  // Field Access of Listing Columns
  if(\Dwij\Laraadmin\Helpers\LAHelper::laravel_ver() == 5.3) {
   $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    $this->listing_cols = ModuleFields::listingColumnAccessScan('Computers', $this->listing_cols);
    return $next($request);
   });
  } else {
   $this->listing_cols = ModuleFields::listingColumnAccessScan('Computers', $this->listing_cols);
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * Display a listing of the Computers.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function index()
 {
  $module = Module::get('Computers');
  
  if(Module::hasAccess($module->id)) {
   return View('la.computers.index', [
    'show_actions' => $this->show_action,
    'listing_cols' => $this->listing_cols,
    'module' => $module
   ]);
  } else {
            return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
        }
 }


 /**
  * Show the form for creating a new computer.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function create()
 {
  //
 }

 /**
  * Store a newly created computer in database.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "create")) {
  
   $rules = Module::validateRules("Computers", $request);
   
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
   
   if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
   }
   
   $insert_id = Module::insert("Computers", $request);
   
   return redirect()->route(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.computers.index');
   
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Display the specified computer.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function show($id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "view")) {
   
   $computer = Computer::find($id);
   if(isset($computer->id)) {
    $module = Module::get('Computers');
    $module->row = $computer;
    
    return view('la.computers.show', [
     'module' => $module,
     'view_col' => $this->view_col,
     'no_header' => true,
     'no_padding' => "no-padding"
    ])->with('computer', $computer);
   } else {
    return view('errors.404', [
     'record_id' => $id,
     'record_name' => ucfirst("computer"),
    ]);
   }
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Show the form for editing the specified computer.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function edit($id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "edit")) {   
   $computer = Computer::find($id);
   if(isset($computer->id)) { 
    $module = Module::get('Computers');
    
    $module->row = $computer;
    
    return view('la.computers.edit', [
     'module' => $module,
     'view_col' => $this->view_col,
    ])->with('computer', $computer);
   } else {
    return view('errors.404', [
     'record_id' => $id,
     'record_name' => ucfirst("computer"),
    ]);
   }
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Update the specified computer in storage.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "edit")) {
   
   $rules = Module::validateRules("Computers", $request, true);
   
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
   
   if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();;
   }
   
   $insert_id = Module::updateRow("Computers", $request, $id);
   
   return redirect()->route(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.computers.index');
   
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Remove the specified computer from storage.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function destroy($id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "delete")) {
   Computer::find($id)->delete();
   
   // Redirecting to index() method
   return redirect()->route(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.computers.index');
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * Datatable Ajax fetch
  *
  * @return
  */
 public function dtajax()
 {
  $values = DB::table('computers')->select($this->listing_cols)->whereNull('deleted_at');
  $out = Datatables::of($values)->make();
  $data = $out->getData();

  $fields_popup = ModuleFields::getModuleFields('Computers');
  
  for($i=0; $i < count($data->data); $i++) {
   for ($j=0; $j < count($this->listing_cols); $j++) { 
    $col = $this->listing_cols[$j];
    if($fields_popup[$col] != null && starts_with($fields_popup[$col]->popup_vals, "@")) {
     $data->data[$i][$j] = ModuleFields::getFieldValue($fields_popup[$col], $data->data[$i][$j]);
    }
    if($col == $this->view_col) {
     $data->data[$i][$j] = '<a href="'.url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/computers/'.$data->data[$i][0]).'">'.$data->data[$i][$j].'</a>';
    }
    // else if($col == "author") {
    //    $data->data[$i][$j];
    // }
   }
   
   if($this->show_action) {
    $output = '';
    if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "edit")) {
     $output .= '<a href="'.url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/computers/'.$data->data[$i][0].'/edit').'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" style="display:inline;padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
    }
    
    if(Module::hasAccess("Computers", "delete")) {
     $output .= Form::open(['route' => [config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.computers.destroy', $data->data[$i][0]], 'method' => 'delete', 'style'=>'display:inline']);
     $output .= ' <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
     $output .= Form::close();
    }

    $data->data[$i][] = (string)$output;
   }
  }
  $out->setData($data);
  return $out;
 }
}
```

**Codigo de la vista**

```html
@extends("la.layouts.app")

@section("contentheader_title", "Computers")
@section("contentheader_description", "Computers listing")
@section("section", "Computers")
@section("sub_section", "Listing")
@section("htmlheader_title", "Computers Listing")
@section("headerElems")



@la_access("Computers", "create")
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal">Add Computer</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
   <span class="caret"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Toggole Dropdown</span>

  </button>

  <ul  class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="export-menu">
   <li id="export-to-excel"> <a href="#"></a></li>
   
  </ul>

 </div>
 
 
@endla_access
@endsection

@section("main-content")

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<div class="box box-success">
 <!--<div class="box-header"></div>-->
 <div class="box-body">
  <table id="example1" class="display table">
  <thead>
  <tr class="success">
   @foreach( $listing_cols as $col )
   <th>{{ $module->fields[$col]['label'] or ucfirst($col) }}</th>
   @endforeach
   @if($show_actions)
   <th>Actions</th>
   @endif


  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

@la_access("Computers", "create")
<div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Computer</h4>
   </div>
   {!! Form::open(['action' => 'LA\ComputersController@store', 'id' => 'computer-add-form']) !!}
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="box-body">
                    @la_form($module)
     
     {{--
     @la_input($module, 'empresa')
     @la_input($module, 'departamento')
     @la_input($module, 'codigo')
     @la_input($module, 'marca')
     @la_input($module, 'modelo')
     @la_input($module, 'n_serie')
     @la_input($module, 'tipo')
     @la_input($module, 'procesador')
     @la_input($module, 'vel_procesador')
     @la_input($module, 'memoria_ram1')
     @la_input($module, 'memoria_ram2')
     @la_input($module, 'memoria_ram3')
     @la_input($module, 'disco_duro1')
     @la_input($module, 'disco_duro2')
     @la_input($module, 'sistema_operativo')
     @la_input($module, 'g_inicio')
     @la_input($module, 'g_final')
     --}}
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    {!! Form::submit( 'Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']) !!}
   </div>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
@endla_access

@endsection

@push('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('la-assets/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css') }}"/>

@endpush

@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('la-assets/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
 $("#example1").DataTable({
  processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/computer_dt_ajax') }}",
  language: {
   lengthMenu: "_MENU_",
   search: "_INPUT_",
   searchPlaceholder: "Search"

  },
  @if($show_actions)
  columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [-1] }],
  @endif
 });
 $("#computer-add-form").validate({
  
 });
});

</script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo de datatables usa ajax, asi que sería practicamente usarlo del lado del cliente y no del servidor, podrías hacerlo pero cuando sean miles de datos la página se saturará y será muy muy lento, asi que no lo sugiero usar de esa forma.

Pero si no manejarás muchos datos ingresa ese codigo javascript en la vista dentro de `@push('scripts')` y configuralo como dice la documentación y deberia estar funcionando correctamente.